# rake db:setup is giving Library not loaded: @rpath/libgssapi_krb5.2.2.dylib error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am on macOS 10.14.2 mojave and am getting an error when I run rake db:setup on my mysql database. It is working fine in other projects and when I did `gem list` in other projects, they both had mysql 0.5.2 and curb 0.9.7. I used to have the same following error except it said libssh2.1 instead of libgssapi_krb5, so I did `brew install libssh2` and then the error changed to this. I then tried doing `brew install krb5` but that did not make a difference. Here is the error:

> mbp-user:project user$ rake db:setup
>   rake aborted!
>   LoadError: dlopen(/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/curb-0.9.7/lib/curb_core.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @rpath/libgssapi_krb5.2.2.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/curb-0.9.7/lib/curb_core.bundle
>     Reason: image not found - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/curb-0.9.7/lib/curb_core.bundle
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in`block in require'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in`require'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/curb-0.9.7/lib/curl.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in`require'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in`load_dependency'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/curb-0.9.7/lib/curb.rb:1:in`'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in`block in require'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in`require'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/user_client-3.7.0/lib/user_client/helpers/http_client.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/user_client-3.7.0/lib/user_client/helpers/authorized_request.rb:1:in`require_relative'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/user_client-3.7.0/lib/user_client/helpers/authorized_request.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/user_client-3.7.0/lib/user_client/adapter.rb:2:in`require_relative'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/user_client-3.7.0/lib/user_client/adapter.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in`require'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in`load_dependency'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/user_client-3.7.0/lib/user_client.rb:2:in`'
>   /Users/user/work/angel/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/user/work/angel/Rakefile:6:in`require_relative'
>   /Users/user/work/angel/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in`'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in`'

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? I'm having the exact same problem. Do you have Xcode Command Line Tools installed?

Comment: I ended up just having to reinstall curb

Comment: @Rahul How did you reinstall it? Didn't work for me and I have same issue in Mojave

Comment: nm, I manually changed LD/CPPFLAGS when installing the gem to include kerberos with '--with-ldflags=-L-L/usr/local/opt/krb5/lib --with-cppflags=-I-I/usr/local/opt/krb5/include' and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Following error when:

```
rake db:drop
```

OR

```
bundle exec rake db:drop
```

Error:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/afsan.abdulali.gujarati/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6@introhive/gems/curb-0.9.10/lib/curb_core.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @rpath/libgssapi_krb5.2.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/afsan.abdulali.gujarati/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6@introhive/gems/curb-0.9.10/lib/curb_core.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/afsan.abdulali.gujarati/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6@introhive/gems/curb-0.9.10/lib/curb_core.bundle
The thing that possibly fixed it:
```

Solution:

```
brew install krb5

brew link --force krb5
```

might give the following output:

```
Warning: Refusing to link macOS-provided software: krb5
If you need to have krb5 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/krb5/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/krb5/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find krb5 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/krb5/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/krb5/include"

For pkg-config to find krb5 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/krb5/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Export paths vars LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/krb5/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/krb5/include"
```

Re-install curb gem

```
gem uninstall curb
gem install curb
```

Side notes on my current system setup:

Mac OS Catalina 10.15.3

I have anaconda3 installed on my system although I have disabled it using the following command:

`conda config --set auto_activate_base false`